# How to fit data in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to write code that read a csv file and then use linear regression for prediction.
The CSV file is like this:

| math | physics |
| --- | --- |
| 17 | 15 |
| 16 | 12 |
| 18 | 19 |

I try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

score_file = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')
math_score = score_file['math']
physic_score = score_file['physics']
cls = LinearRegression().fit(math_score,physic_score)
```

but it gives me this error:

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) where it gives an example of the correct input.

Comment: Your data contains a single feature (score), so just use `math_score.reshape(-1, 1)`, and same for the target data to get proper dimensions. You have to do this because data is expected to be 2D numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

score_file = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')
# score_file = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
#     {'math': [17, 16, 18], 
#      'physics': [15, 12, 19]})

physic_score = score_file['physics']

print(score_file.shape)  # (3, 2)
print(physic_score.shape) # (3,)

# take care of the dimentions
cls = LinearRegression().fit(score_file,physic_score)

# this should be made with a test subdataset or so...
predictions = cls.predict(score_file)

print(predictions) # [15. 12. 19.]
```